# mysql special date output format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

As part of a live chat script which uses php/mysql on serverside and JS/jQuery on clientside i want to output the date of each message in a special format.

If the message was send today like this(for example): `Today 22:30`,
if it was sent yesterday : `Yesterday 12:30`
and if it was send before yesterday it should output this date format: `dd.mm.yy H:i (for example 28.05.14 22:19)`.

Of course i know i could do this with php easily, but for better performance i want to do this using SQL.

I´ve read a lot in the mysql documentation but altough i found a lot of date formating, i couldn´t find something like this.

Now i want to know if this is possible with SQL?

The date of each message is stored as TIMESTAMP in the DB.

Comment: You could do this with a `CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END` expression.

Comment: The cost of PHP doing this is small, ok do it in SQl, what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you think the performance would be better with sql than with php?

Comment: If it's really a performance problem, give the work to JS/jQuery.

Comment: So the performance is the same if i do this with php? This script will run every 3 seconds per online user as ajax call(around 600 peak, 200 average). With php i would do this using the DateTime Class.

Comment: You never know what performs faster until you conduct tests.  However, since you are using javascript anyway, @VMai's suggestion has merit because it transfers the formatting work from your servers to the client.

Comment: yes i didn´t consider i can do this with JS. Thanks to VMai

Answer (score 0):

Use the query below. It must fulfill you requirements(With or without some modifications).

```
SELECT IF(DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE(NOW()),
    'TODAY ' + DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%k:%i'),
    (SELECT IF(DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE(NOW()),
        (SELECT IF(DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y-%m-%d') = (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
            'YESTERDAY ' + DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%k:%i'),
            DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%d-%m-%y %k:%i'))),
            'NO DISPLAY'
        )
    )
) FROM user;
```

**Note:** Here *'created'* is the date which I am intending to fetch from the *user* table.

For **DATE_FORMAT ( )** function description and the parameters used check this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Hope it helps . . .